# how to separate subpages with nginx to point to different nodejs servers

Tags: nginx

I am running two `nodejs` servers on my machine and I want `mydomain.example.com/` to be served by one of the servers except `mydomain.example.com/exception`. I am using `nginx` and tried doing this, but it didn't work. How can this be done?

```
server {
    listen   80;


    server_name mydomain.example.com;

    return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen              443 default_server ssl;
    server_name         mydomain.example.com;
    keepalive_timeout   70;

    ssl_certificate     /etc/chained.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/key;
    ssl_protocols       TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    ssl_ciphers         HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8081;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }

    location /exception {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:9000;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }


}
```

**EDIT**:
My problem is, that the request of `mydomain.example.com/exception` is served by the server on port 8081, not on 9000.

**EDIT 2**:
I misinterpreted the behaviour in the previous edit. `mydomain.example.com/exception` is served by the server on port 9000, but I expected `mydomain.example.com/exception` to be the root for that server, but it did not. I thought this config would make `mydomain.example.com/exception` the equivalent of `mydomain.example.com:9000`, but it makes it `mydomain.example.com:9000/exception`. So the updated question would be: I want `mydomain.example.com/exception` to work exactly the same way as if I accessed the server through the designated port 9000. How can this be done?

Comment: What errors are you getting?

Comment: updated with exact problem

Comment: What does your error log say? I'm having trouble reproducing your error and I'm using a nearly identical config to yours.

Comment: Have you reloaded nginx configuration after change?

Comment: Your comments led me to think I may have misinterpreted the behaviour, so I checked and it is served by the server on 9000, but the problem was, that I thought that the `/exception` would be treated as the root for the server, so the server on 9000 tried to serve `/exception`, which does not exist. I'll update the question.

Comment: I'm getting the same issue as you now, plus it was dropping the `https`.  When I go to `mydomain.example.org/exception/` I don't have these issues anymore. I'm not entirely sure why it's doing that.